# DateTime.Parse with a custom DateTimeFormatInfo throws an exception

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, formatexception, iformatprovider

Why is this code throwing an exception?

```
var dateTime = "2012-03-21_15.12";
var format = new DateTimeFormatInfo()
{
   FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm.ss"
};

// FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
var parse = DateTime.Parse(dateTime, format);
```

Comment: You are assuming that the `DateTime.Parse` method would use the `FullDateTimePattern`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format string and the date string do not match.

You seem to have forgotten either the hours or minutes portion in the date string.

This:

```
 var dateTime = "2012-03-21_15.12";
```

Should probably look like:

```
var dateTime = "2012-03-21-15_54.12";
```

And I suggest using `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2012-03-21-16_15.12", 
        "yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm.ss", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use DateTime.ParseExact as this will take a datetime format pattern as a parameter.

[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)